# Using buffredReader read big files in java

Tags: java

I understand there are two ways read big text files in java. One is using scanner and one is using bufferedreader.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(path));
while (reader.hasNextLine()){
    String tempString = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/(1024*1024.0));
}
```

And the number to be printed is always stable around some value.

However when I use bufferedReader as per edit below the number is not stable, it may increase in a sudden (about 20mb) in one line and then remain the same for many lines(like 8000 lines). And the process repeats.
Anyone knows why?

**UPDATE** 
I typed the second method using BufferedReader wrong here is what it should be

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path)),5*1024*1024);
for(String s = null;(s=reader.readLine())!=null; ){
    System.out.println(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/(1024*1024.0));
}
```

or using while loop

```
String s;
while ((s=reader.readLine())!=null ){
    System.out.println(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/(1024*1024.0));
}
```

To be more specific, here is a result of test case reading 250M file

Scanner case:

linenumber---totolmemory
5000---117.0
10000---112.5
15000---109.5
20000---109.5
25000---109.5
30000---109.5
35000---109.5
40000---109.5
45000---109.5
50000---109.5

BufferedReader case:

linenumber---totolmemory
5000---123.0
10000---155.5
15000---155.5
20000---220.5
25000---220.5
30000---220.5
35000---220.5
40000---220.5
45000---220.5
50000---211.0

However the scanner is slow and that's why I try to avoid it.

And I check the bufferedReader case the total memory increases suddenly in a single random line.

Comment: It may be due to buffer management behind `BufferedReader`...

Comment: Your second loop is a busy loop constantly getting and printing the total memory. It reads a single line of text and then loops constantly.

Comment: You are not really comparing apples to apples when you make the `BufferedReader` use a 5 MB buffer. Besides, you're not going to see a performance improvement with a buffer that big. You can reduce that size to 4 KB or maybe 16 KB without performance penalty. What you will see, is that `BufferedReader` is a **lot** faster than `Scanner`, even if you just use the default buffer size.

Comment: totalMemory is completely irrelevant for what you (presumably) try to learn. Try freeMemory.

Comment: Thanks guys but I am still confused, I am not try to compare the memory they use, I just want to know why the memory of using bufferedReader increase, and increase suddenly in a single random line

Answer (score 3):

Just by itself, a Scanner is not particularly good for *big* text files.

Scanner and BufferedReader are not comparable. You can use a BufferedInputStream in a Scanner - then you'll have the same thing, with the Scanner adding a lot more of "stream" reading functionality than just lines.

Looking at totalMemory isn't particularly useful. To cite Javadoc: *Returns the total amount of memory in the Java virtual machine. The value returned by this method may vary over time, depending on the host environment.*

Try freeMemory, which is a little more interesting, reflecting the phases of GC that occur every now and then.

**Later**
Comment on Scanner being slow: Reading a line merely requires scanning bytes for the line separator, and that's how the BufferedReader does it. The Scanner, however, cranks up java.util.regex.Matcher for this task (as it fits better into its overall design). Using the Scanner just for reading lines is breaking butterflies on the wheel.

Comment: Yes I know Scanner and BufferedReader are not comparable. But I just want to know why the using scanner keeps the total memory stable but using BufferedReader keeps total memory increasing. If the text file is more than 100GB,I will be still fine with scanner but it will exceed the memory with the bufferedreader

Comment: @ZheyuJi No it won't. With the code you posted, each line will get garbage-collected. You should establish that you actually have the problem you fear *before* you try to solve it.  It is probably that `Scanner` uses a `BufferedReader` under the hood.

Comment: @EJP, thanks, but the tend shows that the totalmemory do increase if you could view my updated version of question..And actually I do encounter this problem in cloud computing and when I use scanner if's totally fine but slow, when i use bufferedreader it will exceed the memory. Other logics in my code are same.

Comment: ZheyuJi The data you posted does not exhibit any such trend. There is no out of memory condition, and it shows no increase after 20,000 lines: rather, complete stability. You can read millions of lines a second with BufferedReader, and I have done so many times withou

Comment: @EJP Thanks and you are absolutely right. It is stable with larger file on my local machine. But the test on cloud still shows that it exceeds the memory, I have to add System.gc() per 50000 lines to solve the problem. Anyway my major problem has been solved, I still need some time to figure out why the it fails with cloud and without gc

Comment: @ZheyuJi Don't claim that a certain error occurs without providing the actual code and the stack dump.